# Magento 404 error when clicking any category link

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

Site is www.buffalohistory.com

This started randomly, and no work had been done prior to the issue.

Search is not working either.

Comment: you server configuration is not correct
eg
http://www.buffalohistory.com/index.php/buffalo/vintage-buffalo.html
works
but http://www.buffalohistory.com/buffalo/vintage-buffalo.html
does not

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `AllowOverride All` is set and that you have the `.htaccess` file in your web root.